# Balls-and-bins type problem

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics

Suppose I have an n-by-n array of bins, and I want to choose k (k >= n) bins from these n^2 bins such that each row of the array has at least one bin chosen. How many ways are there of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want $n$ integers, each between 1 and $n$ (inclusive), summing to $k$, and you want to know how many ways there are to do this. It's a standard problem in introductory discrete math, and not suitable for this site. See the faq for more suitable sites, or get a good discrete math text. 

Comment: See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem?wasRedirected=true

Comment: @Gerry: It is not the same problem. Given these numbers, you can choose bins from each row in different ways.


Comment: @Sergei, right you are. Apologies to all. 

Comment: I am wondering why this question is closed? It is surely not as trivial as Gerry said in his first comment.

Comment: Sheldon, please see the "how to ask" page, and revise your question appropriately.  When you have done that, you may flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: Scott - what are you driving at here? You surely have something in mind when you make a comment like that, but reading the "how to ask" page doesn't make it obvious what that is. Perhaps mention what sort of revision you think is appropriate?

Comment: Either people have this confused with a different problem, or else there is something I am overlooking. For example, I don't see a closed form expression for the count when $k=2n$. For $n=4, k=8$, the count is $10896 = 2^4 \times 3 \times 227$. I voted to reopen. 

Comment: This "looks like homework" / "too localized" / "give motivation" / "looks too elementary" policy is beginning to go berserk. The problem is definitely not trivial. I'd suggest the Sylvester sieve (aka principle of inclusion and exclusion) for a sum formula, but I don't know whether an explicit one exists.

Comment: @Sheldon, your question is much better than I originally gave it credit for, but it's still missing one important thing, namely, any evidence that you have put any thought into it yourself. It's hard to get other people interested in a problem when it looks as though you weren't interested enough to do any work on it yourself. 

Comment: This is actually quite a nice question!

Answer (score 7):

The comments were, in my opinion, closer the first time -- this is a standard application of inclusion-exclusion and could be a homework exercise.  The number of ways to choose $k$ boxes from a set of $i$ rows (without worrying about hitting all the rows) is $\binom{in}{k}$.  The number of ways to choose $i$ rows is $\binom{n}{i}$.  Thus the total number of ways to make your choices so that every row gets hit is 
$$\sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^{n - i} \binom{in}{k} \binom{n}{i}.$$
(Perhaps this can be rewritten in other ways that appeal to you more.)

A suggestion to Sheldon: this question has a very elementary look and feel (and indeed it turns out to be very elementary).  When posting a problem of this sort, you should provide some information about why it's of interest to you, so as to help distinguish the homework-cheaters from people who have interesting (e.g., research-related) reasons for needing the solution to elementary problems.  I also agree with Gerry's final comment and an-mo-user's comment here: http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/947/ballsandbins-type-problem-question-closed

Answer (score 3):

More information *would* be nice. The answer by JBL above is perfectly fine but there might be other forms for the answer. In the special case $k=n$ the answer is $n^n$, that is indeed $\sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^{n - i} \binom{in}{n} \binom{n}{i}$ but I like the first form better.For $k$ past $n^2-n$ the answer is just $\binom{n^2}{k}$. In this case the formula given quickly reduces to that.

One could do the sum over all ordered partitions $k=\sum_1^nk_j$ of $k$ into $n$ positive parts of $\prod\binom{n}{k_j}$. That would be practical if $k-n$ is small. One can collect like terms so essentially use unordered partitions with appropriate multinomial coefficients. Hence for $k=n+3$ (if I made no errors) one either has a row with 4 OR a row with 3 and one with 2 OR three rows with 2 things in them (and one thing in each other row). $$\binom{n}{1,n-1}\binom{n}{4}^1\binom{n}{1}^{n-1}+\binom{n}{1,1,n-2}\binom{n}{3}^1\binom{n}{2}^1\binom{n}{1}^{n-1}+\binom{n}{3,n-3}\binom{n}{2}^3\binom{n}{1}^{n-3}$$ $$=n^n\left(\binom{n}{4}+(n-1)\binom{n}{3}\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ $$=n^n\binom{n}{3}\frac{5n^3-11n^2+9n-7}{8}$$

A similar thing would work for $k $ slightly less than $n^2-n.$

So what kind of answer are you looking for and what can you say about $k$?